# Should i access the store to use a State value as payload on a NGRX Effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx

My effect should Load the Filters. For the first time it should use the apiService to load the possible Genres, but in the second time (if theres values on the Store for the Genres) it should load them from the store.
Also, if i already have a value for the releaseDateGte on the store it should use it instead of passing it empty.

```
@Effect()
    genresLoad$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<LoadFilters>(FilterActionTypes.LoadFilters),
      exhaustMap(() =>
        this.apiService.getGenres()
          .pipe(
            map(genres => new LoadFiltersSuccess({genres: genres, releaseDateGte: ''})),
            catchError(error => of(new LoadFiltersFail(error)))
          ))
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component should be **bounded** to your store.
This way, every time it is updated, it will reflect on your UI.

Something like this:

```
this.filters =  this._store.select(getFilterSelector)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._ngOnDestroy),
        filter((filter) => !!filter)
        )
```

After your first dispatch, the view will be in sync.
There is no reason to access the store from effects and do logic that NGRX handlers for you.

If you are trying to avoid the **effect** to run, check state before dispatching *LoadFilters* action.